# Why reading MachineGUID is a virus?

Tags: c++, registry, virus, windows-defender

Why is it that when I read *SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid* from the registry, my program is detected by the Windows Defender as a virus?

Comment: Probably because it's a common pattern for viruses? You need to add your base development directory to the white-list of your anti-virus, to stop it from scanning your programs and executable files.

Comment: Nothing to do with C++ - you'd probably get the same effect regardless of programming language.   It has everything to do with behaviour of your program, and that matching criteria to be reported as a virus by Windows Defender.    At a guess, what you describe is something that viruses or other malware do (e.g. so that they communicate unique identifying security-related information about a machine to home base) so Windows Defender flags the behaviour unless done by a whitelisted program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is it possible to read MachineGuid in a "safe" way? Or replace it with any other unique parameter of the system?

Comment: Windows.System.Profile.SystemIdentification.GetSYstemIdForPublisher or Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for your help, but I'm not developing a UWP application, I'm not sure this method will suit me.

Comment: You can call these methods from classic desktop apps too.